# Error occur when I packaged a IgniteDemo project and try to java -jar it

Tags: ignite

It works fine on my Idea. But when I packaged the project and tried to java -jar the jar, error occur:

Exception in thread "main" class org.apache.ignite.plugin.security.SecurityException: Access to Ignite Internal tasks is restricted.

I defined a runnable task to be executed on server nodes. And it seems that task is "restricted"? But I can still execute the task by running on Idea.

I've packaged all dependencies.

The project is a quick start code I copied from https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start/java. It's just a HelloWorld.java tries to get cache from server nodes and print "hello world".

Comment: How many nodes do you have, and what's the configruation of them? Is it a single server node running somewhere and you have a packaged "Helloworld.java" thick client from the documentation?